# Check duplicate entry before inserting to database to avoid showing database duplicate error - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I call a uid from table organizationalmember by using get_uid() function. Now I want to check if this uid does not have a duplicate in table signatures before inserting it. (sigantures.uid = organizationalmember.uid) So if there is no duplicate i will insert it to the signatures database `$this->db->insert('signatures', $data);` and if it has a duplicate I want to redirect it to another page (probably an error page), I don't want the Database duplicate error to show up. I'm new to codeigniter and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: you can use form validation library it won't let you duplicate value https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=validation

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

Solution 2: also you can use jquery ajax validation on field enter show username already exits
Solution 3: you can post the value and check if the number of rows with specific column and value is greater than 1 then its a duplicate

I would suggest you follow solution 2 i can provide you the code if u want.

Answer (score 0):

I personally code a method in my model to check if there is a duplicated entry and call that method right before call the method to add data into the database.

For example

```
class MyModel extends CI_Model
{
  public function isInDatabase($data)
  {
    // Run a SELECT query with $data to search if there is a record with that $data
    if($data_exists)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  public function insertInDatabase($data)
  {
    // Run an INSERT query with $data
  }
}
```

then in my controller i check for duplicated entry before add `$data`

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller
{
  public function add()
  {
    $data = // Some code to retrive data from user input
    if($this->mymodel->isInDatabase($data))
      $this->mymodel->insertInDatabase($data)
    else
      // Do nothing or show an error page.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you can use the built in Codeigniter Form Validation library to check if the value exists in the database.

```
public function save_data {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('uid', 'UID', 'is_unique[table.column]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        echo validation_errors();
    }
    else {
        $this->model->insert_to_database();
    }
}
```